# How to add build date at assembly description attribute in c#

Tags: c#

I want to know that is there any way to add build date-time in assembly description attribute in c#.
e.g. BuildTime:2022-04-12T08:26:31+02:00.

What I will do after setting this I will check for build date time for some condition??

```html
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("BuildTime:"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"))>
```

Comment: Not in a C# attribute as this must be a constant. Is your csproj in the new format (Microsoft.Net.SDK)? Then you can specify the attribute also in the csproj file and use expressions there, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties

Comment: my project is in Dot Net 2.0 framework .

Comment: Another option would be to patch the attribute value in source by a script before running msbuild

Comment: thanks for the comment @KlausGütter, but I want the  programmatically because If someone other than me forget to mentioned that, then it's should run without limitations.